# Ranorex - how do I use "ExcelDataConnector" to access data?

Tags: ranorex

I am trying to figure out how to use the "ExcelDataConnector" class in Ranorex to access Excel data so we can build dynamic test case interaction.

```
ExcelDataConnector con;
con = new ExcelDataConnector("Test", "C:\\Users\\jonas\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx", "Setup", "", 0);
Report.Info(con.FileName);
```

So I think I have connected to the DataSource. But what do I do from here?

I am looking at the documentation, but I can't figure out what methods to use to fetch the data or loop through records.

*[ExcelDataConnector Class](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/T_Ranorex_Core_Data_ExcelDataConnector.htm)*

Or am I completely out of context here?

I am starting to get the feeling that I have misunderstood the class and what to use it for.

If anyone can confirm or deny my suspicion I would be grateful. And if this is how you are supposed to use the class, please provide a few examples to get me going.

Comment: What is this in? [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)? [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has great information: *[10 Best Practices in Test Automation #5: Data-Driven Testing](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/data-driven-test-automation-with-excel)*.

This is just a sample of what you can see there:

```
public ExcelConnector(string excelFile, string[] inputs, string[] outputs, bool load, UInt16 startRow)
{
    this.excelFile = excelFile;
    this.inputs = inputs;
    this.outputs = outputs;
    if (load)
        this.LoadFile();
    currentRowIndex = startRow;
}

public void LoadFile()
{
    excelObj = new Excel.Application();
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new
                                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    workBook = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(this.excelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                                         Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, false, false);
    Excel.Sheets sheets = workBook.Worksheets;
    worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
}
```

Comment: What is this in? [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)? [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?